# how to fetch on required attribute from database request coming from graphql

Tags: database, graphql

query Languages {
languages {
code
name
}

How can I retrieve specific columns from a database in response to a user's request using Graph QL?

MySQL query => select code, name from languages;

i am new to Graph QL language and unable find any solution online